# Регулярные выражение в SQL запросах

Tags: mysql, sql, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать. Делаю поиск по базе.
Смысл такой: нужно что бы для маленьких слов поиск было только по слову, а не по вхождению.
К примеру: слово "it". Нужно что бы в строках
"IT индустрия"
"Курсы IT"
"IT-Специалист"
находилось, а в строках:
"deportamit"
"position"
"sitel" нет

На данный момент просто добавляю пробелы

```
SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE description LIKE '% it %'
```

Но тогда не находятся записи где IT это начало строки или где стоит тире после слова.
Попробовал RegExp, но почему то не получается

```
SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE description REGEXP '(^|\s)it[^\w]'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне сделать такой поиск или что не так в регулярке.

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Comment: mysql-8.0.26  тип InnoDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте границы слов.

В MySQL 8 и новее можно использовать

```
SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE description REGEXP '\\bit\\b'
```

В старых версиях MySQL можно использовать

```
SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE description REGEXP '[[:<:]]it[[:>:]]'
```

`\b`, граница слова, в начале `it` найдёт совпадение лишь в том случае, если сразу перед `it` имеется начало строки или символ, отличный от буквы, цифры или символа нижнего подчёркивания. `\b` после `it` найдёт совпадение, если сразу после `it` имеется конец строки или символ, отличный от буквы, цифры или символа нижнего подчёркивания.

В старых версиях MySQL `[[:<:]]` обозначает начальную (левую) границу слова, а `[[:>:]]` — конечную (правую).

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный подход -перечислять все 3 варианта явно:

```
WHERE description LIKE 'it %' OR description LIKE '% it' OR description LIKE '% it %'
```

Но в любом случае тут будет косяк когда после него (ну или перед) будет стоять не пробел, а точка, запятая или ещё какой-то знак.

Думаю, лучше подключить специальные инструменты для полнотекстового поиска (например, Elastic Search) и пользоваться ими.